# How can I access images and other data from others html/php websites/servers through php?

Tags: php, html, image, tags, cron

I am creating a kind of database for images and information for something, and I want it to dynamically update when information is added to the other website.
This other site is a wiki-site with one page per "item". Is it possible to have a kind of for-loop or something that can check daily or weekly if there has been added a new page for a new item, and be able to save only the information in a certain tags, like

or , and not like footer etc.?
Some function to loop through all images in a database that I don't really have access to. Everybody has access to the images, but not to the folder that the images is in. Is there any other way than to actually "try" all the names of the images?..

Comment: What kind of rights do you have on the server in question? Are you limited to php or can you install own stuff there? Are you able to setup cronjobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cron to check daily/weekly and use PHP's cURL to pull in the websites details into a string and then you can parse that string however you like.

As for images, if you can't get a directory listing, then you will need to pull from the code as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something daily, write a script that runs once and set it up for cronjob.

From your script you will have to call the wiki site for a list of items and then parse the result from your script looking for new items to add to your database. Sounds feasible, though.